# Sphinx returning bad search results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am using Sphinx with the Thinking Sphinx plugin.  I have indexed a model called Venue with the following code (and the rake thinking_sphinx:index command)

```
define_index do
    indexes :name
    indexes city
    indexes zip
end
```

I obtain the results in my controller with this code:

```
@venues = Venue.search params[:search]
```

and I render them as json.  The problem I have is that when I hit this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/venue/list?search=Baltimo
```

I get nothing.  But when I hit this URL:

```
http://localhost:3000/venue/list?search=Baltimor
```

I get all Venues located in the city of Baltimore.  For some reason that one character makes a difference.  Theoretically, I should be getting all Venues in Baltimore if I just search with one character - 'b'

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Unless you have `enable_star` set to 1 and `min_prefix_len` or `min_infix_len` set to 1 or more, you won't get B to match Baltimore (and even then, I think you need to search for B* to get the match).

What's happening here is that by default, Thinking Sphinx tells Sphinx to use an English stemmer, which allows for *similar* words (by characters, not by meaning) to be considered matches, so it puts **Baltimor** and **Baltimore** in the same basket.

If you want to get any part of any word matched, then you need to put something like the following in config/sphinx.yml:

```
development:
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 1
test:
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 1
production
  enable_star: 1
  min_infix_len: 1
```

Then stop Sphinx, re-index, and restart Sphinx. Once you've done that, then searches for B* should return Baltimore.

Hope this helps.

Comment: sweet, just found that on the sphinx documentation...but couldn't find where it said to put that in the yml. thank you!

Comment: Is there a way where they don't have to type an * at the end? Like search wood would pull up wooden and woodworking without having to type wood*

Comment: Great answer. For anyone who stumbles here, details are found at http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/advanced_config.html. 

One thing to take note of is that setting min_infix_len to 1 will likely decrease performance.